Class inheritance where the children are simple variable-only classes
I am working with some YAML patches. These patches are a similar structure, but contain different values. The values are often difficult to remember, so I want to abstract them away into class instances that I can reference.
Here is the approach I have taken so far:
class YamlPatch:
    def __init__(self, kind, name, namespace, op, path, value):
        target={
            "kind": kind,
            "name": name,
            "namespace": namespace
        },
        scalar=[{
            "op": op,
            "path": path,
            "value": value
        }]

        self.yaml = (target, scalar)

class PatchA(YamlPatch):
    def __init__(self, name):
        namespace = "my-namespace"
        kind = "test"
        op = "replace"
        path = "/test"
        value = "hello"

        super().__init__(kind, name, namespace, op, path, value)

class PatchB(YamlPatch):
    def __init__(self, path):
        namespace = "my-namespace"
        name = "my-name"
        kind = "test"
        op = "replace"
        value = "hello"

        super().__init__(kind, name, namespace, op, path, value)

### Insert 4 or 5 other types of patches here...

patches = []
patches.append(PatchA("hello").yaml)
for app in ["app1", "app2"]:
    patches.append(PatchB(f"/{app}").yaml)

print(patches)

### output: [(({'kind': 'test', 'name': 'hello', 'namespace': 'my-namespace'},), [{'op': 'replace', 'path': '/test', 'value': 'hello'}]), (({'kind': 'test', 'name': 'my-name', 'namespace': 'my-namespace'},), [{'op': 'r
eplace', 'path': '/app1', 'value': 'hello'}]), (({'kind': 'test', 'name': 'my-name', 'namespace': 'my-namespace'},), [{'op': 'replace', 'path': '/app2', 'value': 'hello'}])]

This feels messy and repetitive, especially when you add in type-hinting and comments. Not very DRY. Some of the values are fairly common defaults, and having to __init__ then super() in every child class (patch) doesn't feel good.
I tried using dataclasses, but because the required "input" arguments for the child classes are different, I would have to use the kw_only argument which can be tricky to remember with so many different patches (e.g. PatchA(value="blah") or was it PatchA(name="blah"), I can't remember?).
In short, I'm looking for the quickest and most efficient way to write code which allows me to reference a memorable, simple name (I've called them PatchA and PatchB here but in real code they'll be something unique and obvious to the maintainers) and return the correctly-formatted YAML patch. E.g. print(PatchA).
I am using Python 3.11.
--- EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION
The reason I want to avoid having to use keyword arguments is because each patch has a different set of values, and they're not simple to remember. Also, if the values change, I want to be able to change them in one place rather than every time they're referenced in my code.
Here's a realistic (albeit abridged) example:
class YamlPatch:
  yaml = ...

class PackageApplicationFromGit(YamlPatch):
  path = "/spec/path"
  name = f"application-{application}"
  value = f"/some/applications/path/{application}"

class AppsGitRepoBranchPatch(YamlPatch):
  kind = "GitRepository"
  path = "/spec/ref/branch"
  value = "my-branch-name"

The two patches have the same structure, but wildly different values. These values are all static apart from a single argument, e.g. a branch name or an application name.

Simply turn those into dictionaries and feed them as **kwargs to the dataclass I provided you. As suggested in my last comment under my answer.

I don't fully follow @OysterShucker - do you mean just create standard non-class variables, and then reference those? can you import variables from a separate module? if so I think that might be the simple answer here

I edited my answer with an example

You could use a dataclass and eliminate the subclasses.
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class YamlPatch:
  namespace :str = "my-namespace"
  kind      :str = "test"
  name      :str = "my-name"
  op        :str = "replace"
  path      :str = "/test"
  value     :str = "hello"

  def __post_init__(self) -> None:
    target={
      "namespace": self.namespace ,
      "kind"     : self.kind      ,
      "name"     : self.name      ,
    }
    
    scalar=[{
      "op"   : self.op    ,
      "path" : self.path  ,
      "value": self.value ,
    }]
    
    self.yaml = (target, scalar)
    
  def __str__(self) -> str:
    return str(self.yaml)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  patches = [YamlPatch(name="hello").yaml]
  
  for app in ("app1", "app2"):
    patches.append(YamlPatch(path=f"/{app}").yaml)
  
  print(*patches, sep="\n")

To be honest, the only thing a dataclass is really doing for you here, is eliminating the need for you to do all the boiler-plate in the __init__ method to turn the constructor arguments into properties. It also makes it a lot cleaner, since you won't need a constructor with 6 typed and defaulted arguments in it. If your YamlPatch instances need to be more dynamic, you could refactor the __post_init__ to a property.
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class YamlPatch:
  namespace :str = "my-namespace"
  kind      :str = "test"
  name      :str = "my-name"
  op        :str = "replace"
  path      :str = "/test"
  value     :str = "hello"

  @property
  def yaml(self) -> tuple:
    target={
      "namespace": self.namespace ,
      "kind"     : self.kind      ,
      "name"     : self.name      ,
    }
    
    scalar=[{
      "op"   : self.op    ,
      "path" : self.path  ,
      "value": self.value ,
    }]
    
    return (target, scalar)
    
  def __str__(self) -> str:
    return str(self.yaml)



I tried using dataclasses, but because the required "input" arguments
for the child classes are different, I would have to use the kw_only
argument which can be tricky to remember with so many different
patches (e.g. PatchA(value="blah") or was it PatchA(name="blah"), I
can't remember?).

In your example all instances have the same properties, regardless of how you subclassed the super, so your KW_ONLY argument doesn't make sense. As far as remembering individual patch values is concerned - you should definitely be remembering those. You seem to be looking for a system where you arbitrarily just smack things together and/or have numerous arbitrary classes named after the value they each accept. That's unnecessarily bloated and you'll have just as much trouble keeping track of all the classes as you have keeping track of the necessary value. In short: the lazy approach is more cumbersome than simply not being lazy. You've already proved this to yourself and admitted it with your attempt.

Example from my comment. Not a lookup table, but essentially the same results.
# you have to figure out where `application` is coming from
PackageApplicationFromGit = dict(
  path = "/spec/path",
  name = f"application-{application}",
  value = f"/some/applications/path/{application}",
)

AppsGitRepoBranchPatch = dict(
  kind = "GitRepository",
  path = "/spec/ref/branch",
  value = "my-branch-name",
)

patch = YamlPatch(**AppsGitRepoBranchPatch)


OK I love the idea of having the single YamlPatch class, but it does take me into the territory of the bit you've just edited... :) Let's see if I can explain a bit more clearly. if I have a patch called PackageApplicationFromGit, I know - from its name - that the only value I need to provide is the name of an application, e.g. PackageApplicationFromGit("grafana"). In your example though, I would need to remember which part of the patch to update with the word grafana... which, even now, off the top of my head, I can't

I was hoping I would be able to do something where the name of the class (the "type" of patch I'm using) takes just a single argument and puts it in the right place

@turbonerd - You can do that. It's just a bad idea. You should certainly know what "grafana" refers to. I tend to take a "real world" approach to things. The real world equivalent of what you want is like not remembering if my name is Michael, 49 or New Orleans.

perhaps I should have used real examples, but it's more complex than that. I can remember "grafana", but I can't remember the path or value strings to go with it. I'll update my OP with a real example now, it might make more sense

@turbonerd - You could simply create a lookup table of default arguments for all of the "services" you support and: YamlPatch(**lookup.get('this_service', {}))

I've added a real world example which may explain better. I probably should've done this in the first place but I was attempting to lower the complexity of the question. and by doing so, have made it more complex :rolleyes:

OK great - I think this is the closest I'm gonna get to what I had in my head. thanks for your efforts :)

Instead of derived classes you can hold a dict of changeable parameters and a default dict of values
default = {'kind': 'test', 'name': 'my-name', 'namespace': 'my-namespace',
           'op': 'replace', 'path': '/test', 'value': 'hello'}

patches = {
    'patchA': ['name'],
    'patchB': ['path'],
    'patchC': ['namespace', 'value']
}


class YamlPatch:
    def __init__(self, patch, *args):
        values = default.copy()
        for i, var in enumerate(patches[patch]):
            values[var] = args[i]

        target = dict(list(values.items())[:3]),
        scalar = [dict(list(values.items())[3:])]

        self.yaml = (target, scalar)


pat = []
pat.append(YamlPatch('patchA', 'hello').yaml)
for app in ['app1', 'app2']:
    pat.append(YamlPatch('patchB', f'/{app}').yaml)
pat.append(YamlPatch('patchC', 'outerspace', 'goodbye').yaml)


print(pat)

Output
[(({'kind': 'test', 'name': 'hello', 'namespace': 'my-namespace'},), [{'op': 'replace', 'path': '/test', 'value': 'hello'}]),
 (({'kind': 'test', 'name': 'my-name', 'namespace': 'my-namespace'},), [{'op': 'replace', 'path': '/app1', 'value': 'hello'}]),
 (({'kind': 'test', 'name': 'my-name', 'namespace': 'my-namespace'},), [{'op': 'replace', 'path': '/app2', 'value': 'hello'}]),
 (({'kind': 'test', 'name': 'my-name', 'namespace': 'outerspace'},), [{'op': 'replace', 'path': '/test', 'value': 'goodbye'}])]

If you don't have a case of multiple values it can be simplified to
...

patches = {
    'patchA': 'name',
    'patchB': 'path',
}


class YamlPatch:
    def __init__(self, patch, value):
        values = default.copy()
        values[patches[patch]] = value

        target = dict(list(values.items())[:3]),
        scalar = [dict(list(values.items())[3:])]

        self.yaml = (target, scalar)

...


thanks @Guy - a good answer; succinct, but it strays into the difficulties I've just mentioned in my OP edit

@turbonerd - one way or another you will have to remember something. You're trying to invent the Alzheimer system! :D

I can remember one thing - just not all of the other bits that go with it!
